# Paths on a grid

Tags: combinatorics

> How many paths of minimum length are there from $A$ to $B$ in the grid below?
>   [image]

I thought we should have 16+30+40+30+16 = 132 if we divide the grid into a number of small rectangles but that turned out to be wrong.

Comment: If you play with it, you should find that if you are "always going forward" (i.e. all of your moves are to the right in some direction) then the length of the paths is always the same. So the only question is about taking into account the positions where you can only move to the right in one way. Without the cut corners this is a rather standard problem that you can find in textbooks; with the cut corners you need to just modify the textbook version a little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, lets ignore the two missing squares on the corners.

You will notice that with any path of shortest length, there are always $4$ moves to the Right (R) and $4$ moves Up (U).

For example, one possible path is UURURRUR.

i.e. it is a matter of counting the number of such combinations.

This is given by $C_4^8=70$ since you choose $4$ out of the $8$ positions to place the "U", and the remaining must all be R.

However, two corners are missing, so you have to subtract the number of paths that used the corners which is just $2$.

Hence the final answer is $68$.